# Magento 2: Fetching custom attribute returns 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null'

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to show the value of a custom attribute next to the product price on the product detail page. The attribute has the name 'measurement_unit' and is a drop down menu in the Magento 2 admin.
I have tried calling the attribute several ways, but nothing works. Now I get this error:

'[09-Sep-2020 11:52:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml:50'

The attribute is fetched like this:

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attvalue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('measurement_unit')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $attvalue;exit;
?>
```

The whole file looks like this:

final_price.html

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()) :?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else :?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]);?>

<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attvalue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('measurement_unit')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $attvalue;exit;
?>

<?php endif; ?>



<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()) :?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()) :?>
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl()) ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else :?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to ask if someone can help advice on how I can fetch the attribute correctly?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/282983/71445 that answer works?

Comment: it sorta works as it return the attribute value, but not the attribute text. I modified the code to this wich works:

$_product = $block->getPriceType('final_price')->getProduct();
$attvalue = $_product->getAttributeText('measurement_unit');
echo $attvalue;

Comment: @user12208, This is working in View page but not in Listing page.